# These patterns look exhaustive to me, "Non-exhaustive patterns error" ? Why?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

## Problem

While taking notes from a Haskell book, this code example should return: `Left [NameEmpty, AgeTooLow]`, but it only returns the first case `Left [NameEmpty]`. Then when I pass the function `mkPerson2` results to which it should return `Right Person _ _`, I get back a `Non-exhaustive pattern``` error. I've looked over this code for quite some time, but it looks right to me. What am I missing here? Any explanation on the subject would be absolutely appreciated, thanks!

[Book I'm using](http://haskellbook.com)

## Code

```
module EqCaseGuard where

type Name = String
type Age  = Integer
type ValidatePerson a = Either [PersonInvalid] a

data Person = Person Name Age deriving Show

data PersonInvalid = NameEmpty
                   | AgeTooLow
                   deriving Eq

ageOkay :: Age -> Either [PersonInvalid] Age
ageOkay age = case age >= 0 of
True  -> Right age
False -> Left [AgeTooLow]

nameOkay :: Name -> Either [PersonInvalid] Name
nameOkay name = case name /= "" of
True  -> Right name
False -> Left [NameEmpty]

mkPerson2 :: Name -> Age -> ValidatePerson Person
mkPerson2 name age = mkPerson2' (nameOkay name) (ageOkay age)

mkPerson2' :: ValidatePerson Name -> ValidatePerson Age -> ValidatePerson Person
mKPerson2' (Right nameOk) (Right ageOk) = Right (Person nameOk ageOk)
mKPerson2' (Left badName) (Left badAge) = Left (badName ++ badAge)
mkPerson2' (Left badName)  _            = Left badName
mkPerson2' _              (Left badAge) = Left badAge
```

## Error

```
*EqCaseGuard> mkPerson2 "jack" 22
*** Exception: eqCaseGuard.hs:(54,1)-(55,53): Non-exhaustive patterns in function mkPerson2'

*EqCaseGuard> mkPerson2 "" (-1)
Left [NameEmpty]
*EqCaseGuard>
```

Comment: If you use `-Wall`, then GHC will help you in two ways. It will tell you what non-exhaustive patterns it sees, and it will tell you that the accidental function `mKPerson2'` is missing its type signature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You used a capital K in the first two definitions:

```
mKPerson2' (Right nameOk) (Right ageOk) = Right (Person nameOk ageOk)
 ^

mKPerson2' (Left badName) (Left badAge) = Left (badName ++ badAge)
 ^
```